# Distinct messages and counting

Tags: combinatorics

There are 4 skittles- A, B, C, D.
I can have at most 8 skittles. Each sequence of up to 8 skittles indicate
a different message. It can have repeated elements.

A)What are the # distinct messages ?
B)If I buy 10 skittles. How many ways are there to purchase different skittles?

I am confused how I would go about solving this problem

Comment: Welcome to math.SE.  What have your tried?  What are your thoughts?

Comment: For A, would BBCCC be different from CBBCC?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  the difference in the two parts is that order matters for messages, but not for the collection you buy. Try small numbers by hand-how many one skittle messages are there?  How many two skittle messages?  Does that suggest something?  For B, you are looking for [weak compositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28number_theory%29) of $10$ into $8$ parts.

Comment: First part would be 8 C 4?

Comment: No, combinations presume no repeats.  Did you try the one and two skittle messages?  Skittles here are like letters of the alphabet.  How many one letter messages are there (they don't have to be words)?  How many two letter messages are there?